# Are corner-cases for HTML5 lineJoin specified

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In general, when drawing a sequence of lines, the area affected when `lineJoin` is `"bevel"` will be less than when it is set to `"round"`, and the area affected when `lineJoin` is `"miter"` will be greater than with `"round"`, but each of those has as exception--one documented, and one not.

First of all, it is documented that miter joints which would extend out more than (lineWidth * miterLimit) beyond a vertex get converted into ugly bevel joints.  That behavior yields horrible-looking results when it kicks in (because the joint goes from filling in a much larger area than "round" joints to filling in a much smaller area), but it seems to match documentation.

Behavior is more interesting, however, if a vertex is split in two, with a short or zero-length line between them.  When using miter joints, such a technique makes it possible to "trim" the miter at a configurable angle.  Interestingly, however, if the short line is less than a certain length (or if its length is zero), Firefox renders miter joints as though the short line was an infinitesimal line perpendicular to the bisector of the angle (nice behavior--it's too bad there's no way to request that all line joints behave that way).  Curiously, bevel joints behave like miter joints in that case (the "undocumented" exception to the miter > round > bevel ranking).

*Is there anything which **documents** the behavior of zero- or near-zero length lines in a joined sequence or the criteria for deciding if a line has zero length?  How consistent is browser behavior?*

Behavior was tested in jsfiddle with the following code (should be available at http://jsfiddle.net/A8Eb7/1/ without having to copy/paste).  Note that jsfiddle the second pull-down must be set to `no wrap - in <body>`.

Buttons allow the X and Y coordinates of the right main vertex to be adjusted in increments of 20 pixels, and allow the X and Y displacements of the added vertex to be set to +/-1 or zero, or reduced by a factor of four (to test how small they can get before they are regarded as zero).  The "jinx on" and "jinx off" buttons control whether the system should only plot the three main vertices, or should add additional vertices at the right and also at the end of the line (to show how line-cap behavior can be controlled).

Lines will be shown stroked with round caps/joins, as well as with square/miter and butt/bevel caps and joins.  The round forms will appear as a dark outline, the square/miter as solid light green, and the butt/bevel as brown.  The default settings are to enable jinx with the second point one pixel below the main point; this will cause the right edge of the green line to be vertical.  Clicking "Y=0" will show what happens with a zero-length line (the right edge will be perpendicular to a bisector of the drawn angle).

Demonstration HTML:

```
<canvas id="pic" width=600 height=250>Test</canvas>
<p id="WOW">Testing</p>
<button onClick = "{jointX+=20; show(); }">X +20</button>
<button onClick = "{jointX-=20; show(); }">X -20</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaX=1; show(); }">dX = 1</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaX=-1; show(); }">dX = -1</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaX*=0.25; show(); }">dX /2</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaX=0; show(); }">dX = 0</button><br>
<button onClick = "{jointY+=20; show(); }">Y +20</button>
<button onClick = "{jointY-=20; show(); }">Y -20</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaY=1; show(); }">dY = 1</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaY=-1; show(); }">dY = -1</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaY*=0.25; show(); }">dY /2</button>
<button onClick = "{deltaY=0; show(); }">dY = 0</button><br>
<button onClick = "{jinx=0; show(); }">Jinx off</button>
<button onClick = "{jinx=1; show(); }">Jinx on</button>
```

and JavaScript:

```
var c=document.getElementById("pic");
var p=document.getElementById("WOW");
var cx=c.getContext("2d");
var jointX = 320;
var jointY = 40;
var deltaX = 0;
var deltaY = 1;
var jinx = 1;
function show()
{
    p.innerHTML = "start";
    cx.save();
    cx.clearRect(0,0,600,250);
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.moveTo(40,40);
    cx.lineTo(jointX,jointY);
    if (jinx)
      cx.lineTo(jointX+deltaX,jointY+deltaY);
    cx.lineTo(40,120);
    if (jinx)
    {
      cx.lineTo(40+deltaX,120+deltaY);
      cx.lineTo((40+jointX)/2,(120+jointY)/2);
    }
    cx.lineJoin="round";
    cx.lineCap="round";
    cx.lineWidth=40;
    cx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    cx.stroke();
    cx.lineWidth=35;
    cx.strokeStyle="rgba(255,255,255,1)";
    cx.stroke();
    cx.lineJoin="miter";
    cx.lineCap="square";
    cx.lineWidth=40;
    cx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,255,0,0.5)";
    p.innerHTML = "end1";
    cx.stroke();
    cx.lineJoin="bevel";
    cx.lineCap="butt";
    cx.lineWidth=40;
    cx.strokeStyle="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
    p.innerHTML = "end1";
    cx.stroke();
    cx.restore();
    if (jinx)
      p.innerHTML = "(" + jointX + "," + jointY + ") " +
          "jinx by (" + deltaX + "," + deltaY + ") ";
    else
      p.innerHTML = "(" + jointX + "," + jointY + ") " +
          "jinx off";        
}
show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The official specification for the canvas 2d context can be found on the website of the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/). Any behavior not described in this document is up to the implementing browser.

Comment: Section 3 of the document does not seem to describe the observed behaviors; indeed, the behavior of the miter joints in Firefox when the dx,dy is 0,0 is simultaneously contrary to specification (which says zero-length line segments should be pruned, implying that they not affect how joints are rendered) but useful (allowing consistent-looking corners with very acute angles without requiring the use of round joins).  Do you know of any efforts to document a good way of drawing such corners?

Comment: Upon some further investigation, it appears that the transformation matrix in FireFox uses type `float`, but coordinate processing is otherwise done in type `double`.  Something of an odd combination I think, given that the result of one transformation is often used as input to another.  Is such usage legitimate?